CLI tool for sending commands to TCP server
I'm building a CLI app for my peer-to-peer TCP node. What i want to do is start and access it using terminal commands. Usage example:

{executable_name} start starts a node in the background
{executable_name} connect --address ip_addr connects to another running node by address

If i start a node (which is essentially both TCP server and client) from terminal, the terminal blocks since the server is listening for connections. I've tried to use the same compiled executable in another terminal window, but it doesn't work like that. How do i start my app in the background, or access the process itself? If a node would have a state that i manage in-memory, how do i access it? Should i use fork a process, daemonize it or something? Also i thought of making a terminal console for it (like a psql console for postgres, for example), so i was wondering, which is the better way to do it?

Why not just run it in background mode?  ./your-process &
